# Как узнать количество обновленных строк?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli, update

```
$query_up = "UPDATE `" . $res_str . "` SET Hostname = '$data[1]', Ports = '$data[2]', Mac_address = '$data[3]', Mac_vendor = '$data[4]', date = '" . date('Y-m-d H:i') . "' WHERE IP = '$data[0]'";
    $resaddnet = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'], $query_up);                                
    printf("Затронутые строки (UPDATE): %d\n", mysqli_affected_rows($GLOBALS['link']));
```

В результате всегда выводит 1, как сделать так, чтобы выводило количество обновленных строк?

Comment: Так вы вроде все правильно делаете. может оно действительно всегда по 1 строке обновляет ?

Comment: бывает что несколько соединений с БД открывают и в коде потом путают, может это

Answer (score 1):

У вас всё верно и в запросе и в возврате затронутых строк. Всё об этом [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

В Вашем запросе условный оператор WHERE принимает ip - очень такую уникальную запись. Соответственно изменения претерпевает только одна строка.

А количество обновлённых строк, например, за сессию или за другой период Вам лучше хранить отдельно, в той же $_session:

```
session_start();
/*... a lot of useful code ...*/
if($rows = mysqli_affected_rows($GLOBALS['link'])):
    $_session['aff_rows'] += $rows;
endif;
```

Comment: (В Вашем запросе условный оператор WHERE принимает ip - очень такую уникальную запись.) Если IP уникальное поле, то да, а так - не факт.

Comment: @azhirov1991 Вы правы, если там база из адресов разных подсетей, ip не будет уникален. Будем считать что вопрошавший работает с одной)